# Haskell - Write a function countPositives to count the positive numbers in a list (the ones strictly greater than 0)

Tags: haskell

For example, `countPositives [0,1,-3,-2,8,-1,6]  ==  3`.

I am having trouble running it, I believe its something to do with data types.

```html
countPositives :: Int -> Int
countPositives xs = length [ x | x <- xs, x > 0]
```

Comment: `Int` is a single integral *number*, not a list of numbers. For a list of numbers, it is `[Int]`.

Comment: Why the down-votes? This looks like a fairly well-written, totally legitimate question from a new user. Not very interesting, but totally appropriate.

Comment: I also disagree with the close votes. It's obviously reproducible, and "typo" means a mechanical error on the keyboard, which is not the same as "I don't know the difference between Int and [Int]".

Comment: @amalloy, I would call it a generalized typo. The OP got a useful answer and hopefully learned what they needed to, which is great, but I don't think there's much here for others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An `Int` is a *single* integral number, at least all numbers between *-2<sup>29</sup>* and *2<sup>29</sup>-1* are representable by an `Int`. For example, `42` is an `Int`, not a *list* of `Int`s. You can make use `[Int]` for a list of `Int`s, so:

```
countPositives :: [Int] -> Int
countPositives xs = length [ x | x <- xs, x > 0]
```